# Question on a claim in a paper

Tags: matrices, harmonic-analysis, diagonalization, spectral-graph-theory

> Let $\odot$ represents the point-wise product and $L$ is the Laplacian
> matrix (which is symmetric positive semidefinite matrix) and it can be diagonalized as $L = \Phi \Lambda\Phi^*$ and $\Phi = [\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_N]$ and $\Phi \Phi^* = \Phi^*\Phi = I$ and $\Lambda = Diag(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_N)$ is the eigenvalue matrix such that $\lambda_i \geq 0$ for all $i$.
>
> In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09816.pdf) (page 3), the authors generalized a similarity notion on compact manifolds to the graph setting claiming that
>
> $$ \alpha (\varphi_k,\varphi_\ell) \in [0,1]. $$
> where $\varphi_k$ and $\varphi_\ell$ are the $k$-th and $\ell$-th eigenvectors of graph Laplacian matrix, respectively.

I am curious to write a rigorous mathematical reasoning for this. My derivations are as follows.

> $$\alpha(\varphi_k,\varphi_\ell) = \frac{\|e^{-tL} (\varphi_k \odot
> \varphi_{\ell})\|}{\|\varphi_k \odot \varphi_{\ell}\|} \leq
> \frac{\|\Phi e^{-t\Lambda} \Phi^{*}\| \|\varphi_k \odot
> \varphi_{\ell}\|}{\|\varphi_k \odot \varphi_{\ell}\|} \leq 
> \|e^{-t\Lambda}\| = e^{-t\lambda_{\min}}\leq 1,
> $$
> where $\lambda_{\min}$ is the largest eigenvalue of $L$.

I just get confused about that. Would you please elaborate on this case?

---

Note:
Based on the nice comment of @MaoWao, it is clear that the problem is about the "negative sign" in the definition of this metric.

---

Additional note:
*This question from the **first** concerning the graph setting (NOT the manifold - as the graph Laplcian matrix and its diagonalization are used and an example also provided for that). Moreover, the paper is actually about generalizing that concept from manifold to the graph setting addressing that equation when doing this generalization. Then the answer on manifold is not helpful and it is off-topic.*

Comment: I think you just have some trouble with the signs. The $t$ in the definition of $\alpha(\phi_j,\phi_k)$ is the unique solution of $e^{t\lambda_j}+e^{t\lambda_k}=1$, which forces $t$ to be non-positive. Also, if $t<0$, then $\|e^{tL}\|=e^{t\lambda_{\min}}$, which is $\leq 1$ by assumption.

Comment: Of course, surely $t>0$ by the claim of paper. Moreover, I think all the eigenvalues are effective rather than just the two corresponding eigenvalues.

Comment: Tbh, I don't even see a proper definition of $\alpha(\phi_j,\phi_k)$ for graphs in the paper. In any case, you have to either take $e^{-tL}$ instead of $e^{tL}$ in the definition of $\alpha$ or take $t<0$. That's actually quite natural since $\Delta$ is a negative operator, so the correct analog of $\Delta$ on graphs would be $-L$ and not $L$. Finally, you need some defining equation for $t$ since $\alpha(\phi_j,\phi_k)$ does not depend on $t$. But whatever $t\leq0$ you choose, $0\leq \alpha(\phi_j\phi_k)$ will always hold.

Comment: Definitely $t > 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment. Yes, I just confused by the sign.

Answer (score 1):

I have not read the paper carefully enough to understand what everything means, but this property might just follow by Cauchy-Schwarz. Because $p(t,x,\cdot)$ and $p(t,\cdot,y)$ are probability distributions, we have (using Fubini towards the end)
\begin{align}
\|e^{t\Delta}f\|_{L^2}^2
&= \int_M|e^{t\Delta}f(x)|^2\,dx = \int_M\left|\int_Mp(t,x,y)f(y)\,dy\right|^2\,dx\\
&\le \int_M\left(\int_Mp(t,x,y)\,dy\right)\left(\int_Mp(t,x,y)|f(y)|^2\,dy\right)\,dx\\
&= \int_M\int_Mp(t,x,y)|f(y)|^2\,dy\,dx\\
&= \int_M|f(y)|^2\int_Mp(t,x,y)\,dx\,dy\\
&=\|f\|_{L^2}^2.
\end{align}

Comment: @Amin Why do you want to delete the question?

Comment: @Amin No, actually I don't. I have thought about your problem for some time, read the paper, and also spent time on writing my answer. You could at least check it. Then I get the credits and can delete it.

Comment: Actually I first checked your answer. That is related to the case on manifold but I need the discussion on graph rather than manifold. Totally different.

Comment: But the paper is on manifolds. So, the answer is legit. Just open a new question for graphs.

Comment: On page 3 (which you refer to) I don't see any graphs.

Comment: But you only refer to page 3 and the inequality written there. You asked why -- I gave the answer.

Comment: Well, you edited your question yesterday when I already had given my answer. The only question in your first post was about $\alpha\in [0,1]$ on page 3 of the paper. I answered. If you have another question, open up another one.

Comment: The graph laplacian only appeared in an example, which seemed to have nothing to do with the question. So, I ignored it. Next time, try to pose the question as you mean it.

Comment: You also need to read it carefully. Anyway your answer is not helpful.